# How to disable XST FF/Latch trimming or hide warnings about it

Tags: xilinx

Can anyone explain to me how can I disable XST FF/Latch trimming ? 
In this particular example, I know why trimmings are occurring (I don't want to go into details), but they are occurring on very large std_logic_vector (two vectors with 128 bits).

That said, I get many warnings and can't see if anything else is wrong (that I would care about). So I would like to hide warnings or disable FF/Latch trimming. Is that possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ISE you can hide particular warnings from the message window IIRC.  I think right-clicking the message might be the way.

Personally, I tend to use a pure command-line flow - including a script which "edits out" the messages I have defined as being "uninteresting" or "supposed to happen" via a set of regexps in a side-file.  Of course, then I have to validate the regexps :)